# Erratic login screen behavior happens without changes to the boot configuration

Tags: login

I'm a new Ubuntu user. Since I installed it on my computer I am experiencing all five of the following erratic cases when I start the computer and try to log in.

1. I enter the password and start without problems.
2. I enter the password and ask it again indefinitely without being able to start (login loop).
3. I enter the password and detect it as invalid, but I'm going to "start with another user", select the same user, set the same password and it allows me to start.
4. The previous case, but without letting me in.
5. The computer starts without asking me for the password.

All these cases happen without changes to the boot configuration, so I'm pretty confused. What should I do?

Comment: You're using 18.04, right?